# How do I show that $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^{2n}}=x _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2n};1+\frac{1}{2n};-x^{2n}\right)$?

Tags: integration

This came up when I was trying to evaluate $\int\sqrt[n]{\tan(x)} \, dx$, after a couple of substitutions the integral boiled down to
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}-n\int x^{n-1} \left ( \int\frac{dx}{1+x^{2n}} \right) \, dx.
$$

Comment: $\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2 n};1+\frac{1}{2 n};-x^{-2 n}\right)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(-x^{2 n}\right)^{-k}}{2 k n+1}$